# wrong react native map boundaries when the map is rotated

Tags: react-native, google-maps, maps, google-maps-android-api-2, react-native-maps

#### Summary

I'm using react-native-maps for the following issue.

I'm trying to get the visible map boundary using `mapRef.current?.getMapBoundaries`, it returns `{ northEast: LatLng, southWest: LatLng }`, drawing a polyline of those coordinates is fine until you rotate the map, then it's going to give you wrong coordinates,

is there a better way to get visible map boundaries?

I used to get an output like `{ topLeft: LatLng, topRight: LatLng, bottomRight: LatLng, bottomLeft: LatLng }` from other libraries,

is there a way to get four points like those that represent the map bounradaies.

#### Reproducible sample code

```
import { useCallback, useMemo, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import MapView, { BoundingBox, Polyline } from 'react-native-maps';

const initialRegion = {
  longitudeDelta: 0.15110325068235397,
  latitudeDelta: 0.1793406486560123,
  longitude: 55.26689613237977,
  latitude: 25.212185223887573,
};

export type ExampleProps = {
  //
};

export const Example: React.FC<ExampleProps> = () => {
  const mapRef = useRef<MapView>(null);

  const [mapBoundaries, setMapBoundaries] = useState<BoundingBox>();

  const handleRegionChangeComplete = useCallback(async () => {
    const mapBoundaries = await mapRef.current?.getMapBoundaries();

    if (!mapBoundaries) return;

    setMapBoundaries(mapBoundaries);
  }, []);

  const polylineCoordinates = useMemo(() => {
    if (!mapBoundaries) return [];

    return [mapBoundaries.northEast, mapBoundaries.southWest];
  }, [mapBoundaries]);

  return (
    <MapView
      ref={mapRef}
      initialRegion={initialRegion}
      onRegionChangeComplete={handleRegionChangeComplete}
    >
      <Polyline coordinates={polylineCoordinates} />
    </MapView>
  );
};
```

#### Steps to reproduce

- run the code.
- change the region (by moving in the map).
- a polyline, will be drawn from top right into bottom left.
- now try rotate the map and change the region.
- the polyline will not be drawn properly.

#### Expected result

the polyline should always be from top right into bottom left, or maybe the lib should give us 4 points instead of 2.

#### Actual result

the lib will not give me the right boundaries when rotation is applied.

#### React Native Maps Version

^1.8.0

#### What platforms are you seeing the problem on?

Android

#### React Native Version

0.72.6

#### What version of Expo are you using?

Not using Expo

#### Device(s)

Samsung Galaxy S21 FE

the polyline should always be from top right into bottom left, or maybe the lib should give us 4 points instead of 2.

Comment: Can you try using Expo to make it easier to reproduce?